# What to do about too many low quality answers?

Tags: discussion

I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986386/sorting-an-array-of-strings-with-java/41587198#41587198) here. Just a some sorting code, no explanations, nothing. Well, at least, decently formatted. I then had a 
closer look on that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986386/sorting-an-array-of-strings-with-java) ... and woha, tons and tons of such "here some code" answers; a lot of subtle formatting or content problems.

I *guess*: this is not how it is supposed to work?! But what would be the correct response (downvote all the LQ stuff, and put in a delete request)?

Or be pragmatic, and just ignore such "c..p magnets"?

Comment: _"i guess thats what you want. Good luck"_ <-- Imo, that's enough reason to downvote already.

Comment: Crappy questions tend to produce crappy answers... I filled a bug report about that.

Comment: at **230K views** this question apparently attracts careless passers by from search engines who pollute it. At the very least it would better be [protected](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protected-questions), although it probably deserves a moderator attention to do [Atwood cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773). Hey, and since you've got 20K consider VtDing low quality answers with negative score

Comment: And everyone there seems to answer the wrong question...

Comment: @gnat Totally unrelated, but this "great" question has more views than I have reached people during 9 months of partially really hard work. That really helps with motivation :-|

Comment: [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202652/life-isnt-fair)

Comment: @gnat Sure thing. Especially when some question goes "hot" in the SE network; and you watch some mediocre answer receiving more upvotes in a few hours than your very best answer will ever receive in total. One of the few occasions where I think "yep, that daily cap really makes sense".

Comment: regarding HNQ you just [rub salt into my wounds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:165773+[hot-questions]) :)

Comment: @gnat Well. Ahem. Running your query using my user id; and getting 0 results ... feels a bit more like a salty wound on my end ;-)

Comment: Related: [What to do with new answers that just repeat old ones?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326171/1983854)

Comment: @gnat y u no post as answer ^^

Comment: @TylerH I'd rather prefer to have a [meta-tag:canonical] post on these matters. It's like 20th time I see question like this over here in last year. But since the _real_ solution for issues like that ("Atwood cleanup") requires diamond moderator commitment there is too little I can do as a regular user

Comment: Maybe just declare such popular questions to be finished answering (even more than just protected)? Apart from that being pragmatic is always good.

Comment: @gnat You are probably right about such questions (as mine here) coming up too often. But see the positive side: that means that at least those 20 questions last year pointed to bad answers; so some helpful cleanup took place as consequence of that!

Comment: to avoid misunderstanding I don't complain about questions like your. I vote up all of them and am going to do so in the future. I can't even complain about losing 5-10 reps at every such question because of downvoting poor answers because almost all of this rep eventually gets back when these are deleted (like it happened this time). I am merely mildly sad that there seem to be no clear commitment of diamond moderators to do as Atwood recommended in cases like that

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When I encounter a low quality answer:

- I look for more low quality answers under the question (including late redundant, duplicate, and link-only answers).
- I down-vote *all* of those low quality answers.
- If any are duplicates, I post a comment linking to one or more of the decent previous answers.
- If any are link-only, I post a comment indicating as such and flag as "Not an Answer".
- If any are exceptionally bad, (ab)use the "Not an Answer" or "Very Low Quality" flags with the hope they end up in the Low Quality Review queue to get deleted.
- If there are duplicates that were obviously copy and pasted verbatim from other answers, I'll flag for "moderator intervention" explaining as such with links.
- I check the question itself because it may be a magnet for crap and also deserve a down-vote and a potential close-vote.

Comment: Nice list there. I was tempted to accept the "many more upvotes" answer; but I think your approach fits much better to my "clean code boy scout" rule of "leave the place in better shape than you found it".

Comment: In my experience, Not an Answer flags I have raised on old, link-only answers are always accepted and the answer deleted.

Comment: @Aaroninus Maybe it's that the ones the I've had declined had up votes as well.

Comment: @cpburnz That's odd, I find my flags get accepted, even on highly upvoted or accepted answers, though the answer is usually not deleted in those cases.

Answer (score 31):

Downvote and move on.

For answers like that, there isn't really a good flag. (Which means it shouldn't be flagged).
But you're free to vote as you see fit. ;-)

Comment: Don't forget that as a 20k+ user, you can also vote to delete, if you think it's warranted.

Comment: @CodyGray: True, but in this case, it does attempt to answer. Imo, there's no really good reason to delete it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ0nb.png

Comment: @Cerbrus I understand the "general" policy behind your statement; but well: as we can see here, there are many really useless answers. Wouldn't there be a certain "merit" in deleting these code only answers ... given the fact that they add **nothing** new to the topic? But well, given the comment from BoltClock ... lets see how that question and the answers look tomorrow.

Comment: @GhostCat: So much for that 1-rep answer downvote cost, huh?

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for bringing *that* one up. But you know, when 3, 5 people downvote, it cant be revenge anymore. Besides, back then I asked about *long standing* questions, not answers ;-)

Comment: hey @BoltClock given your diamond I think you [could do better for a question with 230+K views](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773). _"Answers that are strong candidates for deletion:
* belong to low rep or anon users with no real commitment to the community * are provably duplicate, that is, were added well after (30+ mins later) other answers that contained the same exact information * are short in length * do not explain much of anything..."_

Comment: @gnat: Funny you mention that. After downvoting the answers I was wondering if I should delete them all (since, as I'm sure you're aware, I'm *all* about deleting late low-effort dupe answers). But then I thought, *you know what, I haven't heard from gnat in a while*. So I decided to be a little lazy.

Comment: your laziness cost me -9 @BoltClock

Comment: @gnat No worries, those -1 came back a few minutes ago, well most of them I guess.

Comment: I just downvoted your answer, as you suggested.

Comment: Someone actually _did_... wut o.O

Answer (score 9):

These sort of questions tend to attract lots of these sort of code examples. I don't know a whole lot about Java, but a lot of these answers don't even relate to the asked question as such, it's just some random snippet of sorting code. *Shrug*.

Personally, if I encounter these questions in a review queue I leave a comment in the form of:

> Thanks for your answer, but it looks like someone else already answered this question several years ago: [..link to most similar answer..]

Half the time the poster will realize their mistake and self-remove the answer. Problem solved.

If they don't, *shrug*. I downvote if it's truly bad or misguided, but most of the times I don't. It's already at the bottom of the answer list and not likely to get any upvotes. I don't see how downvoting accomplishes anything other than potentially angering someone.

---

If I encounter it "by chance" – as you seem to have done – I typically don't do anything unless it's really bad or misguided, for the same reasons mentioned above.

Comment: I get your point. On the other; I am all about "clean code". And there we follow the "boy scout rule" - when you visit a place you leave "more clean". On the other hand ... I guess I could use up my whole reputation to downvote such answers ... and would still just scratch the surface of the problem.

Comment: @GhostCat What else is your reputation for, if not to spend downvoting bad posts?

Comment: @Servy Sure, when you are one of the 6 digit semi Gods that is easy to say .

Comment: @GhostCat You only really need a few thousand rep for the privileges, you have already long past the point at which you need your rep for anything but downvotes or perhaps the occasional bounty.

Comment: @GhostCat You are complaining about a lack of rep? You know, it's not just 10K+ that read meta... :P

Comment: @Servy "you only need a few thousand rep for the privileges" yes, 20,000.

Comment: @TylerH Which he has a fair bit more than.  And that's even assuming you care about all of the privileges, which most users tend not to.

Comment: "It's already at the bottom of the answer list and not likely to get any upvotes." I guess that is the crucial point here. Still I wonder why people waste their time producing bad quality duplicates.

Comment: @Trilarion A) they probably dont spend more than 1 minute for such an answer B) they are new and simply hope that putting whatever content on a high-rep-view question will somehow translate into 10 upvotes in 5 minutes

Comment: @GhostCat Dunno ... I think many simply just see the question and never look over the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Add your own!​​​​​​‌​‌​‌​‌​​​​​​​‌​‌​‌​‌​​​​​​​‌​‌​‌​‌​​​​​​​‌​‌​‌​‌​​​​​​​‌​‌​‌​‌​​​​​​​‌​‌​‌​‌​​​​​​​‌​‌​‌​‌​​​​​​​‌​‌​‌​‌​​​​​​​‌​‌​‌​‌​

Comment: You can very well claim "nobody else had this idea" before. And honestly, I find your answer much funnier than the one by "Your Common Sense" that suggested "Upvote and move on" showing -21 downvotes right now! And really nice: that joke-within-the-joke nuance - as one could argue that you just gave a *low quality* answer ;-)

Comment: Damn. Clever use of invisible characters.