# Low Quality Review - Duplicate Answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, low-quality-posts

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51786468/697477) came up in my LQP queue and from the review page it seemed like a genuine attempt to answer the question. It lacked a lot of good formatting, so I edited it.
Something was rubbing me wrong about it, though. So, I went back to view the question and found that the answer is a duplicate of one that's been there since May.

I'm posting this for general insight on what others think, but I suppose it's also a feature request for the LQP queue to be able to see other answers. Perhaps only if they are very similar to other answers. It's been a while since I've reviewed though, so I'm not sure how common of an occurrence this is.

Comment: It's pretty common to see answers like that from low rep. users in that queue. If you want to be thorough, you have to look at all the other answers on the question (as a bonus you get the chance to down-vote them). [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341329/369450) is my general procedure which equally applies to the queue.

Answer (score 9):

This, an answer being an (almost) verbatim copy of an existing one, especially an upvoted one, is a more common occurence than anybody could like.
I am not going into the reasons for that, suffice to say that explaining it would probably give wrong ideas to the wrong people.

It does however mean that it is a very necessary step in the judgement of the low quality queue to double check by leaving the review and seeing the question with all existing answers.
Take into account that many a "very low quality" flag might have been raised exactly for the reason of being a copy of an existing answer.

Note however, that if an answer is very similar, to the point of containing almost identical solution code, but adds any additional insight, maybe only a different angle of explanation, then it is not bad just for being similar.
Especially in case of the impression that "copying" the answer took more time than was spent on the original, I tend to only look on the content and stop comparing.