# Show more datapoints that make up the trend that counts toward a review ban

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-suspension

So I caught my first-ever review ban:

[image]

As near as I can tell, [the review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28864465) wasn't a review audit that I failed. In fact, I don't recall failing any review audits recently, but that's not really the point.

As I understand it, one cannot catch a ban from a single action; there has to be a trend. The problem is that the notification only *shows* a single action, which I'm guessing is the culminating one. Now, assuming that a review ban is supposed to be instructional and corrective, it would *really* be helpful if I could see more of the datapoints on the trend. I've tried stepping back through my review history, but it only shows "Reviewed" (or "Review Audit Passed"), without really telling me if any of those reviews were contributors to the ban.

I'm fairly sure that a moderator can pull up a list of contributing items, if they happen to drop by, but wouldn't it save everyone a lot of effort if more than one item were shown in the notification to start with?

Comment: *"As I understand it, one cannot catch a ban from a single action;"* - incorrect, a moderator can ban you from review as and when they choose, and often will if you are reviewing incorrectly - In particular, why did the answer in [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/28864465) need to be deleted?

Comment: Because it is identical to the first answer, except it doesn't have as good an explanation.

Comment: IIRC, that is a downvote/comment reason in the LQP queue, not a deletion reason, indeed you'll find the queue instructions say: *"Recommend deletion or Delete if you think that an answer does not address the question at all, is link-only, or is incomprehensible."*, notably, duplicate answer is not listed. In addition, the two answers were posted within 25 minutes of one another and could reasonably be expected to have been written independantly. Duplicate answers are something generally checked in FP/LA queues. Will need a mod to weigh in either way.

Comment: You'll also find duplicate answer not listed in the [LQP FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029), while it _is_ listed in the [FP FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030)

Comment: Review bans which are automatically imposed by the system for failing audits do require failing more than one audit, at least in total. However, review bans which are imposed by a moderator may be for a single action. That is substantially more likely for short review bans, where the moderator is imposing the ban as feedback to tell you that the action you took in a review was incorrect, so you can learn from the information provided. A review ban is the primary method moderators have of providing feedback to you that something you did in the review queues wasn't the correct action.

Comment: As an aside the text in the ban message should probably read "*nothing wrong with these posts*"

Comment: Your question here is unclear. Your title along with the [tag:feature-request] tag indicate that you're proposing a change to the system. However, the content of your question reads substantially like "please explain my review ban". The dichotomy between the two makes it difficult to know what the focus should be for an answer (e.g. an answer which addresses/shows support/show disagreement with the feature request, or an answer which addresses your specific review ban).

Comment: For the Low Quality Posts these may help you to understand when you should delete: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) and [Reviewing my Low Quality Posts Reviews](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397302/reviewing-my-low-quality-posts-reviews). It's basically the same as [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: The [recommendation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326171/what-to-do-with-new-answers-that-just-repeat-old-ones) to delete duplicate answer only applies for new answers to older questions with existing answers where the new answer is 1) not very good (e.g. just a code dump, barely an explanation) and 2) does not provide more information than existing answers. That is not the case here.

Comment: "Identify, then improve or delete low quality posts." says the Queue... The 'Identify' part has already been done, or the Post wouldn't be in the Queue, then it feels like the only Choices/Actions are 'Improve' or 'Delete'... ... And 3 out of the 4 Reviewers went for "Recommend Deletion" (x2) + "Delete" (x1) (with 50k-Rep!), only one went for "Looks OK"... => Maybe an Idea to send all (active) Reviewers to some "Review Training" from time to time...

Answer (score 10):

You were suspended manually by a moderator for incorrectly reviewing the single post linked in the suspension message, which you correctly note was not an audit.  It is entirely possible (common, even) to be *manually* suspended for a single incorrect review, just not for an automatic suspension over a single incorrect action.  This distinction is likely in no small part because the audit system is sometimes itself mistaken about the correct result of a review.

Such suspensions already have the feature you're requesting here—[the moderator can select up to six reviews to show you for why you're suspended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356377/165261):

[image: Step 2 of Review Suspension UX for mods: Select reviews tasks from the most recent tasks performed by the user, for inclusion in the review suspension message]
<sup>image via above-linked post</sup>

Comment: Ok, so does that mean that a ban that is triggered automatically will show multiple points (or the last several?) that contributed to the ban?