# How can I vote for deletion of First Answers (not Late Answers) that repeat previously posted answers?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, first-answers

The following question:
[Which review action should be taken for First Answers (not Late Answers) that repeat previously posted answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424134/which-review-action-should-be-taken-for-first-answers-not-late-answers-that-re) was marked as a duplicate of another question whose [accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326214/13970434) says:

> In all cases where I have decided that a later answer is providing
> nothing valuable that was not provided in earlier answers I do
> downvote and **I do vote to delete where I can.**

This makes a lot of sense since those answers are not adding any value to the site. However, I can't find this action among the review actions.

Comment: The user posting that answer has >20K reputation so probably are talking about the ability to vote to delete answers of score −1 or lower https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/145673 - the quote "I do vote to delete where I can" is not in response to a question scoped to review queues and just seems to be about when they are seen organically.

Comment: you need at least 10k rep to be able to vote to delete. To be a top of the line janitor on this site, you need to create a big pile of junk first :)

Comment: @Gimby with at least 10k rep you can vote to delete on closed questions (> 48 hours after they have been closed) but still need to wait until you reach 20k to be able to cast delete votes on answers, as already mentioned by Martin Smith above your comment.

Comment: @jps I wasn't contradicting it, merely adding to it. Maybe I should have said "to begin to be able to cast any kind of delete vote".

Comment: Do you want to delete them? If Alice beat Bob by a few minutes and both spent time writing good-quality answers that break down and explain the problem and solution and perhaps tie up some loose threads, let them stay. If it's a few hours or days and there's literally no value added, even a different explanation of the same solution that might be more accessible to some other readers, maybe that's expendable. I'd start with downvotes though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which review action should be taken for First Answers (not Late Answers) that repeat previously posted answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424134/which-review-action-should-be-taken-for-first-answers-not-late-answers-that-re) (My view is that the answer you are talking about should be clarified in place, rather than having a separate Q&A.)